# How do I use this smoreg model to manually predict the future price?

Tags: model, machine-learning, weka, prediction, forecasting

I have historical livestock prices data with more than 1000 instances, and 3 attributes. I have used WEKA (Waikato Environment for Knowledge Analysis) workbench. I have created ARFF files for training data and testing data. When I run I get the predicted prices, and it gives me the SMOreg model.

My question is how do I use the equation so that when I enter new data it should give me the predicted price?

The model gives this equation;

```
Predicted price =  + 0.2209 * (normalized) SEX  - 0.3164 * (normalized) GRADE  +  0.3937
```

Under SEX, 1 is female while 2 is male. Under grade, 2 is weight equal or above 100kg, while 3 is weight below 100kg.

The problem is when I try using this equation substituting sex and grade values it does not give me the real predicted price. 
Later I want to use the equation on Android so that one can use an app for price prediction.

Below are;
 1. Part of ARFF file.
 2. SMOreg model from the training data
 3. Part of predicted price

```
ARFF   
    @relation trainingDataset  
    @attribute SEX numeric  
    @attribute GRADE numeric  
    @attribute PRICE numeric  

    @data  
    1 , 2 , 364000  
    1 , 3 , 306000   
    2 , 2 , 530000   
    2 , 3 , 336000   
    1 , 2 , 400000   
    1 , 3 , 277000   
    2 , 2 , 558000   
    2 , 3 , 340000   
    1 , 2 , 356000   
    1 , 3 , 302000
```

When running, it gives the following output

```
SMOreg
weights (not support vectors):  
 +       0.2209 * (normalized) SEX  
 -       0.3164 * (normalized) GRADE  
 +       0.3937
```

## Number of kernel evaluations: 562330 (95.457% cached)

```
Actual Class,SMO Predicted  
648000.0, 606226.8428201795  
360000.0, 401190.9898681232  
416000.0, 463105.0101318615  
324000.0, 258069.15717980522  
648000.0, 606226.8428201795
```

...........................

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You have to de-normalize the prediction.

Somewhere in your available data should be the normalization parameters, the mean and stdev (standard deviation) of the original data.  Your data were all normalized, likely using the transformation

```
y' = (y - mean) / stdev
```

Where y is the original price and y' is the normalized price.

Now you have to reverse that process.  Solving for y:

```
y = y' * stdev + mean
```

Do this to each of your predictions, and you should have the desired predicted price.